# Vue - Cómo mostrar los datos de un Getter en la vista

Tags: vuex

Desde un Getter asíncrono `getInfoUsuarioBBDD` recibo datos de firebase.

A través de console.log(db) veo que me devuelve un objeto con la info:
`-MlUWf1yWBXZ6_JUn5kE: {apellido: 'Garcia', ciudad: 'Any', cp: '12345', direccion: 'any', direccion2: 'any', …}`

No consigo mostrar esos datos en la Vista.

**Getter**

````
   ```
 async getInfoUsuarioBBDD(state){
  try {
     const res = await fetch(`https://tienda1-default-rtdb.europe- 
     west1.firebasedatabase.app/infoUser/${state.user.localId}.json? 
     auth=${state.user.idToken}`)
     const db = await res.json()
     return db
  } catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
````

}
```

**Vista.vue**

````
    ```
  <template>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="modal" v-if="getInfoUsuarioBBDD">
        {{getInfoUsuarioBBDD}}
        {{getInfoUsuarioBBDD.nombre}}
      </div>
    </div>
 </template>
 <script>
    import { mapState, mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
    export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['getInfoUsuarioBBDD']),
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['setInfoUsuarioBBDD', 'setCompraUsuarioBBDD']),
    }
 }
</script>
   ```
````

Comment: Ese getter.. no esta bien.. tu getter solo deberia devolver el dato del state que vos queres (o algo filtrado en tal caso) todo eso que esta ahi, deberia estar repartido entre una action (la parte asincronica), una mutation (la parte que modifica el state) y luego el getter solo devuelve el dato que queres... el getter no es asincronico, por eso no te funciona... el unico que es asincronico son las actions...

Comment: Vaya, quería evitar tirar de states.  Cuando dices que los getters no pueden ser asincronicos, te refieres a que no deberian de serlo?  O que no funcionan? Porque  sí que veo que a traves de la consola me devuelve un objeto